# Trying to unstake EFX coin after 4 years

Tags: unstake

I have been staking effect.ai token EFX for more than 4 years now and honestly didn't touch it during that time.
Now I wanted to unstake it, but when I try to connect my wallet here
https://dao.effect.network/stake/

it doesn't seem to connect with my Scatter app which is installed locally on my MacBook Pro.

It just 0 balance on the website.
On Scatter, it doesn't show the staked EFX tokens at all.

Can anybody help me here? Thanks a lot in advance!